# css pseudo selector not working on div

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Im trying to create a fixed menu on the side of my page. However, I want it partially hidden and to expand on hover only. I tried to do this with css and pseudo selectors but it won't work.

HTML:

```
<div id="sideMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>Wide Screen</li> <!--turn sidebar on/off-->
        <li>Random Border</li> <!--randomize vidcontain border-->
        <li>Control Bar</li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sideMenu{
    position: fixed;
    left: -95px;
    top: 250px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color: #D4D048;
    z-index:-1;
    display:block;
}
#sideMenu:hover{
   left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/eH9Cr/

Comment: @MarcB, nothing happened when I went over it. Using Chrome.

Comment: @Mr. Alien [you beat me to it!](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/SnjJV/), and I'm using Chrome as well.

Comment: Hmm yea you're right it works over there. I think it might have to do with my z-index on my other elements. Perhaps they are covering it.

Comment: Yea I just changed the index and it works now. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Note that hover states may not be available on user agents with touch input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-index on the div prevented the div from recognizing it was being hovered and therefore the rules pertaining to hover were not applied. Increasing the z-index position solved this issue.

Comment: Please accept your own answer to prevent it from being listed as unanswered.